# iOS application closes with no error when trying to retrieve push message data attribute

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'am sending push messages to application with `react-native-firebase` and it look's wonderful ! Also, I need to receive some portion of data, so sending data something like this

```
$request_body = [

    'to' => $TOKEN_ID,
    'notification' => [

        'title' => 'Title',
        'body' => 'Body',
        'sound' => 'default',
    ],
    'data' => [

        'key' => 'value',
    ],
];
```

I'am trying to listen open push message event as bellow

```
this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {

    const notification = notificationOpen.notification;
    const data = notificationOpen.data;

    setTimeout(() => {

        Alert.alert(data.key);
    }, 5000);
});
```

After 5 second left, application closes without any error message. If changing `Alert.alert(data.key);` with `Alert.alert(notification.title);` application work`s fine and show an alert. Can someone explain to me, why retrieving data is not work properly?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found a solution

```
const data = notification.data;
```

or

```
const data = notificationOpen.notification.data;
```